# Jquery passcode (4 digits number) validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to validate a simple pin/passcode form and then be able to submit if correct .

How can I validate this pin number 
If passocode is wrong display a message. 
if passcode is correct then eneble button and proceed!
Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" id="" name="pass" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" id="" name="pass" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" id="" name="pass" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" id="" name="pass" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
 $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            pass: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                equalTo: "0000"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pass: {
                required: "Please provide a PIN DIGIT",
                minlength: "Please enter at least 4 numbers"
            }
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E4Gz6/

Comment: @EOF thanks yes you totally right! I've just removed it

Comment: If your checking this with client side script anyone can see what the pin is supposed to be?

Comment: @Max I'm prototyping for now, I know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for this you will have to use jQuery Ajax.

Make a simple PHP script, which will take POST data, which will be your password, and if the password matches, for example with your database, or directly hardcoded to the PHP script, it will echo true otherwise false. If you wont use PHP, and you will store the PIN in your Javascript, it will be visible for others.

**EDIT:** This should be working according to your design.

```
<form>
<input type="password" maxlength="1" id="digit1" class="pass" />
<input type="password" maxlength="1" id="digit2" class="pass" />
<input type="password" maxlength="1" id="digit3" class="pass" />
<input type="password" maxlength="1" id="digit4" class="pass" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $(".pass").keydown( function() {
 pass=$("#digit1").val() + $("#digit2").val() + $("#digit3").val() + $("#digit4").val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "passCheck.php",
    data: "password="+pass,
    success: function(html){    
    if(html=='true')    {
         $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else    {
         $("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');

    }
   },

  });
});
```

});

PHP: (just in case)

```
$pass = $_POST["password"];

if ($pass == "1234")
echo "true";
else
echo "false";
```

**EDIT 2:** 
If you dont want to use PHP and Ajax, simply for prototyping and playing with it, you can use simple check, but its strongly not recommanded, as everyone can see the pass in the code:

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $(".pass").keydown( function() {
 pass=$("#digit1").val() + $("#digit2").val() + $("#digit3").val() + $("#digit4").val();

 correctPass = "1234";  
    if(pass==correctPass)    {
         $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else    {
         $("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help! yes, I'm not using php as I'm prototyping for now. So would you be able to change your script with "onKeyDown" please?

Comment: But this concept will be still pretty easy hackable. If you want it for something serious, be sure to check the password also with script after you submit it.. Because its easy to remove the "disabled" attribut directly in browser and then click the Submit button.

Comment: @sanguisuga sure, give me a minute, I will try it myself to be sure I dont miss anything. But I think you won't be able to use PHP script on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sure, I don't need PHP, as I'm prototyping

Comment: you still there? There's a way display a message into this? wrong or correct?

Comment: @sanguisuga well you can either make some <div> container, with ID and then calling $("#container").html("Message"); in the "if" statement for correct code, or "else" for wrong code, or you can just add something like: alert("Message"); which will show you a popup message.